# auto resize iframe with chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was asked to resize iframes according to it's content. After long hours of searching, I've finally got it to work as needed but it only works on firefox. I need it to work at least on chrome, ff and ie. Here is the script

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight; //ff
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentDocument.body.offsetHeight; //chrome
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight;

        }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
}
//-->
</script>
```

and the iframe code

```
<iframe name="result" id="iframe" seamless src="action/search.php" width="100%" onLoad="autoResize('iframe');" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 scrolling="no" style="border:0; overflow:hidden">
    </iframe>
```

any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904934/resize-dynamic-iframe-problem-with-chrome

Sounds like same problem solved.

Comment: I've tried it but it just opens a new tab everytime i click on the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onload="if (window.parent &amp;&amp; window.parent.autoIframe) {window.parent.autoIframe('tree');}
```

in iframe and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autoIframe(frameId){
        try{
            frame = document.getElementById(frameId);
            innerDoc = (frame.contentDocument) ? frame.contentDocument : frame.contentWindow.document;

            if (innerDoc == null){
                            // Google Chrome
                frame.height = document.all[frameId].clientHeight + document.all[frameId].offsetHeight + document.all[frameId].offsetTop;
            }
                    else{
                    objToResize = (frame.style) ? frame.style : frame;
                    objToResize.height = innerDoc.body.scrollHeight + 18;
                    }
        }

        catch(err){
                alert('Err: ' + err.message);
            window.status = err.message;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. I get an error saying Err: frame is null in ff and "Err: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null" in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the height on the element directly, you should probably set it as an attribute:

```
var heightAttr = document.createAttribute("height");
heightAttr.value = newheight;
document.getElementById(id).attributes.setNamedItem(heightAttr);
```

Or you could set it in the css object:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.height = (newheight) + "px";
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not actually very experienced in javascript. I'm actually still trying to learn the basics, maybe you can help me and give me more details on how to do this? Thanks for the help btw