# use of "#" in hyperlink in iframe causes iframe to resize

Tags: php, html, iframe

I curently have the following settup, A php require sits at the top of a page with users details in it, and an iframe sits below it with a preview of their website im currently working on. If i have created a tempory hyperlink that just goes to "#" then the top user details header dissapears and the iframe covers the full page. This  dosent happen, however if a normal link is clicked.

This is the page that contains the header and iframe:

```
<? require '../userhead.php' ?>
<!doctype html>
<body style="z-index:1000;width:100%; margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;">
<br>
<iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;border:0px;z-index:-1;" src="/WestAncroft2"></iframe>
```

The links in the iframe page are like this:

```
 <li><a href="#">Supply</a></li>
```

Any ideas?
Many thanks,
Tommy

Comment: please elaborate your question clearly :)

Comment: code example with generated html. even better a fiddle if you can.

Comment: ok, so I have a page which contains a php include, and an iframe, the iframe contains a page which has the following address in it <a href="/WestAncroft2/#> which should simply make a blank link that dosent go anywhere, but when i click on it it changes the size of the iframe.

Comment: @TecHunter the page is here http://tommyburnmusic.com/pass/index.php use the username and password listed on the right

Comment: Which link is that? And in which browser does it go wrong?

Comment: have you tried `<a href="#" target="iframe">Supply</a>` and `<iframe name="iframe" ....`

Comment: Oh, I see it only goes wrong in Chrome, not in any of the other browsers.

Comment: @MrLister Do you have any idea why that could be? might it be something to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904934/resize-dynamic-iframe-problem-with-chrome

Comment: No idea. Could be, but if it's a timing problem, why isn't it more random; why does it consistently go wrong with one link and not with the others? I also tried to make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/7GkNV/1/) with the minimal markup needed to duplicate the problem, but then it doesn't go wrong at all.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried :

```
<? require '../userhead.php' ?>
<!doctype html>
<body style="z-index:1000;width:100%; margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;">
<br>
<iframe name="iframe" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;border:0px;z-index:-1;" src="/WestAncroft2"></iframe>
```

And in links :

```
<li><a href="#" target="iframe">Supply</a></li>
```

Or you could do the other way around. Make your main page out of the frame and load the userhead.php inside a div like :

```
$('#userhead').load('../userhead.php');
```

Or use a iframe for the userhead if you like it that way. I personnally dislike iframe...