# Dynamically resizing Iframe to work with Chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic, resize, height

i'm looking by a week for a code to dynamically resizing an IFrame (by its content) to work with Google Chrome.
I tried every code I found, failing miserably.
Can someone help  me?

Comment: we can help you after you showed us your best try.

Comment: Show us what you tried and we can help identify where you went wrong.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904934/resize-dynamic-iframe-problem-with-chrome

Answer (score 0):

This works for all Chrome, I.E. and FF.
(I didn't test it on other browsers)

```
    $(function () 
     {
        $('iframe').height($('iframe').contents().height()); 
     });
```